# Using reflection to set a property of a property of an object

Tags: asp.net, reflection, c#-3.0

I've got two classes.

```
public class Class1 {
   public string value {get;set;}
}

public class Class2 {
   public Class1 myClass1Object {get;set;}
}
```

I've got an object of type Class2. I need to use reflection on Class2 to set the value property... i.e, if I were doing it without reflection, this is how I would go about it:

```
Class2 myObject = new Class2();
myObject.myClass1Object.value = "some value";
```

Is there a way to do the above, while using reflection to access the property "myClass1Object.value" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is absolutely possible using standard reflection, although unless you have generic rules it seems as though this would be some one-off logic that might be better accomplished without reflection.

Comment: @Quintin I do realize that my example is a bit contrived; however, my actual situation is actually much more complex than the example I posted and does indeed reflection to accomplish.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically split it into two property accesses. First you *get* the `myClass1Object` property, then you *set* the `value` property on the result.

Obviously you'll need to take whatever format you've got the property name in and split it out - e.g. by dots. For example, this should do an arbitrary depth of properties:

```
public void SetProperty(object source, string property, object target)
{
    string[] bits = property.Split('.');
    for (int i=0; i < bits.Length - 1; i++)
    {
         PropertyInfo prop = source.GetType().GetProperty(bits[i]);
         source = prop.GetValue(source, null);
    }
    PropertyInfo propertyToSet = source.GetType()
                                       .GetProperty(bits[bits.Length-1]);
    propertyToSet.SetValue(source, target, null);
}
```

Admittedly you'll probably want a bit more error checking than that :)

Comment: Very nice. I had ventured down that road already trying to get the PropertyInfo of the first Property, but I ran into a wall when I tried to call SetValue because I didn't actually have the source (i.e, you supplied the missing piece with the GetValue). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I had a recursive version of this. This implementation is much better: adopted!

Comment: I've tried doing something equivalent with fields of a struct (FieldInfo, Get/SetField, etc.) but didn't have any luck.  Would that be expected to behave differently?  For example, struct A contains struct B which contains an int i.  SetProperty(source, "B.i", 4) does not change a.B.i to 4.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ryan: At that point you'd be fetching property `B`, which will take a *copy* of it, mutating the copy, but then not assigning the copy back to `B`. Fundamentally, you should avoid mutable structs because they make this sort of thing painful.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your reply.  That makes sense.  I worked around this by throwing things (the field and source object) on a stack in the for loop and then popping and assigning on the way back out.  It may not be pretty, but it works.

Comment: @Ryan: Well, that works around this particular problem - but I'd still very strongly urge you to avoid using mutable structs.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for answers to the case where to Get a property value, when the property name is given, but the nesting level of the property is not known.

Eg. if the input is "value" instead of providing a fully qualified property name like "myClass1Object.value".

Your answers inspired my recursive solution below:

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(object source, string property)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = source.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    if(prop == null)
    {
      foreach(PropertyInfo propertyMember in source.GetType().GetProperties())
      { 
         object newSource = propertyMember.GetValue(source, null);
         return GetPropertyValue(newSource, property);
      }
    }
    else
    {
       return prop.GetValue(source,null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static object GetNestedPropertyValue(object source, string property)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = null;
        string[] props = property.Split('.');

        for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            prop = source.GetType().GetProperty(props[i]);
            source = prop.GetValue(source, null);
        }
        return source;
    }
```