# How to know if a PropertyInfo is a collection

Tags: c#, reflection

Below is some code I use to get the initial state of all public properties in a class for IsDirty checking.

What's the easiest way to see if a property is IEnumerable?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
  protected virtual Dictionary<string, object> _GetPropertyValues()
    {
        return _getPublicPropertiesWithSetters()
            .ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, pi => pi.GetValue(this, null));
    }

    private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> _getPublicPropertiesWithSetters()
    {
        return GetType().GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.CanWrite);
    }
```

## UPDATE

What I wound up doing was adding a few library extensions as follows

```
    public static bool IsNonStringEnumerable(this PropertyInfo pi) {
        return pi != null && pi.PropertyType.IsNonStringEnumerable();
    }

    public static bool IsNonStringEnumerable(this object instance) {
        return instance != null && instance.GetType().IsNonStringEnumerable();
    }

    public static bool IsNonStringEnumerable(this Type type) {
        if (type == null || type == typeof(string))
            return false;
        return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType) && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
```

Comment: Note that a string is an IEnumerable too

Comment: better:
p.PropertyType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)

Comment: i use this: typeof(IEnumerable<object>)

Comment: Small change to compile (empty generic required):

typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType) && property.PropertyType != typeof(string)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 22):

I agree with Fyodor Soikin but the fact that is Enumerable does not mean that is only a Collection since string is also Enumerable and returns the characters one by one...

So i suggest using

```
if (typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
```

Comment: You are right about the string of course, but your solution fails (try it with List<string>()). See my update for the code I wound up using. Cheers!

Comment: This fails because no constructed type (like `List<string>`) can be assigned to a generic type ( `ICollection<>`) (in fact, you can't declare a variable of type `ICollection<>`). So better use `typeof(ICollection)` (as suggested by the editor), which will also make it work for non-generic collections.

Comment: Very much indeed

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
private bool IsEnumerable(PropertyInfo pi)
{
   return pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEnumerable));
}
```

Comment: I recently noticed that `x.IsSubClassOf(y)` will return false if x == y.  In this situation, if the property happened to actually be of type `IEnumerable`, then the function would return false.

Comment: That is interesting, I've honestly never actually used this logic in this exact context, so I'm glad you pointed that out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "pattern matching". This works for both `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
private void OutputPropertyValues(object obj)
{
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.GetValue(obj, null) is ICollection items)
        {
            _output.WriteLine($"    {property.Name}:");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                _output.WriteLine($"        {item}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _output.WriteLine($"    {property.Name}: {property.GetValue(obj, null)}");
        }
    }
}
```