# System.Reflection.PropertyInfo getPropertyInfo(System.Type type, string NavigationPath)

Tags: .net, data-binding, reflection

I need a function with the following signature:

```cs
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo getPropertyInfo(System.Type type, string NavigationPath)
```

or in VB:

```vb
Function GetPropertyInfo(Type As System.Type, NavigationPath As String) As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
```

Usage:

```
Dim MyPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(GetType(Order),"Customer.Address.State.Code")
Dim DisplayName As String = MyStringFunctions.FriendlyName(MyPropertyInfo.Name)
```

It uses period-delimited path navigation.
I can't figure out how to harness the databinding framework to do this.
First hurdle is it seems only to want to work with objects (not types),
second hurdle is I couldn't even get it to work with objects outside of a control.
I would think under the hood somewhere databinding deals with types and property types; it would have to!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, that doesn't use binding infrastructure.
I still think binding would do a better job.

```vb
  Function GetPropertyInfo(Type As System.Type, NavigationPath As String) As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
    For Each Part As String In NavigationPath.Split(".")
      GetPropertyInfo = Type.GetProperty(Part)
      If GetPropertyInfo IsNot Nothing Then
        Type = GetPropertyInfo.PropertyType
      End If
    Next
  End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For data binding you'd want the property's value rather than the property itself (i.e. return `object` rather than `PropertyInfo`).

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1954746/389966) provides such implementation which can also be easily modified in case you actually want the method to return the property and not its value.

Comment: I wasn't trying to do databinding. I was trying to leverage the databinding infrastructure to implement this function.