# How to generate Expression<Func<T, TPaginatedKey>> expression based on a string?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I am implimenting Generic Entity Repository as described in Pro Asp.Net Web Api Http Web Services in

Asp.Net  Tugberk Ugurlu et al.

The paginated function is as follows. Please focus on the third parameter 'keySelector'

```
public PaginatedList<T> Paginate<TPaginatedKey>(int pageIndex, int pageSize, Expression<Func<T, TPaginatedKey>> keySelector,
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    m_EntitiesContext.Set<T>().OrderBy(keySelector);
    ... // Removed some code here.
}
```

The above method is called as follows.

```
m_Repository.Paginate<short>(cmd.Page, cmd.Take, x => x.Id, null);
```

So here the argument to the third parameter `keySelector` is `x => x.Id`. As you can expect, it is ordering by Id, and it is hard coded to Id. Now I want to generalize so that at run time I should be able to order by Id, ModifiedDate, FirstName, or what ever based on a string parameter such as "Id" or  "ModifiedDate" or "FirstName". So can someone please how I can generate or create the `Expression<Func<T, TPaginatedKey>>` expression based on a string? I guess it should be simple enough, but I am unable to do it.

Comment: Why base it off a string?  Also, have a look into Expression Trees (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx), its for constructing dynamic expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is something called [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx),  which allows you to build dynamic expressions.

Taken from the example from the link, this is how they do a dynamic order by

```
MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "OrderBy",
    new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType, queryableData.ElementType },
    whereCallExpression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(pe, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

// Create an executable query from the expression tree.
IQueryable<string> results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(orderByCallExpression);
```

Comment: The example isn't really dynamic, always does `.OrderBy(x => x)`.

Comment: The following so question is what I ended up following.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336713/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-for-run-time-sorting