# VB.NET: Instantiate a nested property by reflection

Tags: vb.net, reflection, propertyinfo

I want to set the values of the properties via reflection. In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294242/how-to-set-vaues-to-the-nested-property-using-c-sharp-reflection) they propose a solution. But the problem with the solution is that it is not instantiating the properties. But I want to check and instantiate the properties if necessary. My DTO is:

```
Public Class root
    Public Property Printing() As rootPrinting
End Class

Public Class rootPrinting
    Public Property Printer() As String
    Public Property PrinterBatch() As String
End Class
```

Now for setting the properties I have defined the following function:

```
Public Sub SetProperty(ByVal target As Object, ByVal compoundProperty As String, ByVal value As Object)
    Dim properties As String() = compoundProperty.Split("."c)
    For i As Integer = 0 To properties.Length - 1 - 1
        Dim propertyToGet As PropertyInfo = target.[GetType]().GetProperty(properties(i))
        target = propertyToGet.GetValue(target, Nothing)
        if IsNothing(target) then
            if propertyToGet.PropertyType.IsClass then
                target = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyToGet.PropertyType)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Dim propertyToSet As PropertyInfo = target.[GetType]().GetProperty(properties.Last())
    propertyToSet.SetValue(target, value, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Then I call it like this:

```
Dim configObject as New root
SetProperty(configObject , "Printing.Printer","skjfkd")
```

If before calling `SetProperty(configObject,...)` I instantiate `configObject.Printing` then it will work fine:

```
Dim configObject as New root
configObject.Printing = new rootPrinting()
SetProperty(configObject , "Printing.Printer","skjfkd")
```

Otherwise after calling `SetProperty(...)`, `configObject.Printing` will be `Nothing`.
It seems that when calling `Activator.CreateInstance(propertyToGet.PropertyType)` the reference to the original object is lost. While the object in the function is really initialized, the main object remains `Nothing`. How can I instantiate the class property correctly?

Comment: The DTO classes have public constructors and properties in your example.  I assume in the actual project these are all private?

Comment: @ParrishHusband No, in the actual project the the properties are public, too. There just I have private members which are bound to the properties. But to shorten the text I have changed it for this sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. The problem was solved. To solve the problem the code has to be modified as following:

```
Public Sub SetProperty(ByVal target As Object, ByVal compoundProperty As String, ByVal value As Object)

   Dim properties As String() = compoundProperty.Split("."c)

   For i As Integer = 0 To properties.Length - 1 - 1
      Dim propertyToGet As PropertyInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(properties(i))
      Dim property_value = propertyToGet.GetValue(target, Nothing)
      If IsNothing(property_value) Then
         If propertyToGet.PropertyType.IsClass Then
            property_value = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyToGet.PropertyType)
            propertyToGet.SetValue(target, property_value)
         End If
      End If
      target = property_value
   Next

   Dim propertyToSet As PropertyInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(properties.Last())
   propertyToSet.SetValue(target, value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This question/answer was very helpful to me (thanks Code Pope!), I needed the same code in C#:

```
public void SetProperty(object target, string compoundProperty, object value)
{
    var properties = compoundProperty.Split('.');

    for (int i=0; i < (properties.Length - 1); i++)
    {
        var propertyToGet = target.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i]);
        var property_value = propertyToGet.GetValue(target, null);
        if (property_value == null)
        {
            if (propertyToGet.PropertyType.IsClass)
            {
                property_value = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyToGet.PropertyType);
                propertyToGet.SetValue(target, property_value);
            }
        }
        target = property_value;
    }

    var propertyToSet = target.GetType().GetProperty(properties.Last());
    propertyToSet.SetValue(target, value);
}
```