# AutoMapper: How to MapFrom with string parameter when flattening

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

The MapFrom method of AutoMapper has two overloads:

```
.MapFrom(Expression<Func<object, object>>
```

and

```
.MapFrom<TMember>(string)
```

The first overload can be used like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(order => order.Customer.DateOfBirth))
```

I tried the second overload like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom<DateTime>("Order.Customer.DateOfBirth"))
```

But it does not work when using a property of an association. Who nows how this second overload can be used when using flattening?

I ask this because I look for a way to do the mapping dynamically; for example:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom<DateTime>(givenPropertyString))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the `MapFrom` overload `.MapFrom<TMember>(string)` doesn't work well with nested properties (I might be wrong here). But, for your questions, you can create a custom method to get nested child property value using reflection. And use it to map any property value dynamically with `string NestedPropertyName`.

This is the custom method (source of method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954746/using-reflection-in-c-sharp-to-get-properties-of-a-nested-object))

```
public static object GetNestedPropertyValue(object obj, string nestedDottedPropertyName)
{
    foreach (String part in nestedDottedPropertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        PropertyInfo info = obj.GetType().GetProperty(part);
        if (info == null)
            return null;

        obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And you can use this method in `MapFrom` dynamically (for any property), like this

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Date, 
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetNestedPropertyValue(src, "Order.Customer.DateOfBirth")));
```

Comment: You are right, it does not work with nested properties. I just changed my question with that before I saw your answer.

Comment: @JorritSteetskamp Still this answer should be relevant :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several options to map types dynamically using Automapper.

First of all, Automapper `DynamicMap` is supposed to use if the source type is unknown at compile time. It allows to specify only the destination type:

```
var message = Mapper.DynamicMap<ICreateOrderMessage>(order);
```

And about your question about `MapFrom(string)` - [it works](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/4924d02e63ba55978567cf6251c14ad7304d986a/src/UnitTests/Projection/MapFromTest.cs) exaclty you suggest:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserModel, UserDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom<string>("FirstName"));
```

Probably nested properties like your "Order.Customer.DateOfBirth" just are not supported.